# Load Array of Integers into AVX Register

Tags: c, simd, avx

I am currently looking into AVX Intrinsics to parallelize my code.
As for now I would like to write a benchmark an see how much speedup i can receive.

```
void randomtable (uint32_t crypto[4][64])
{
    int k = 1;
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        k++;
        for (int j=0;j<64;j++)
        { crypto[i][j]= (k+j)%64; }
    }
}
int main (void)
{
uint32_t crypt0[4][64];
randomtable(crypt0);
__m256i ymm0 = _m256_load_si256(&crypt0[0][0]);
}
```

My problem and question is how do I load the first 8 elements of the array into the ymm0?

i am compiling with gcc -mavx -march=native -g -O0 -std=c99

compile error: error: incompatible types when initializing type '__m256i' using type 'int'

Comment: You seem to be doing this already with `_mm256_load_si256` (apart from the obvious typo) - can you be more specific about the actual problem ?

Comment: well I get a compile error. Using GCC. -mavx and -march=native are set as CFLAGS......error: incompatible types when initializing type '__m256i' using type 'int'

Comment: OK - see answer below...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line has a typo and is missing a cast:

```
__m256i ymm0 = _m256_load_si256(&crypt0[0][0]);
```

It should be:

```
__m256i ymm0 = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i *)&crypt0[0][0]);
```

Note that you'll probably need to use AVX2 if you want to do anything further with the data (i.e. integer arithmetic, etc), so you should compile with `-mavx2`.

Comment: @PaulR - can one load a linked list into AVX register or do they have to be arrays ?

Comment: @gansub: SIMD works best with contiguous data, i.e. arrays. Note also that linked lists tend to have inefficient cache/memory access patterns, so for performance-critical applications they are often implemented using arrays and indices rather than the usual dynamically-allocated structures and pointers.